# Find indexes from list in Elixir

Tags: arrays, functional-programming, elixir

With [`Enum.find_index/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#find_index/2), we can find the index of an element.
However, if a same element occurs several times, how can we do?

I would like to have this behavior:

```
iex> find_indexes(["a", "b", "c", "b", "b"], fn(x) -> x == "a" end)
[0]

iex> find_indexes(["a", "b", "c", "b", "b"], fn(x) -> x == "c" end)
[2]

iex> find_indexes(["a", "b", "c", "b", "b"], fn(x) -> x == "b" end)
[1, 3, 4]
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find a exact function in library, so tried to implement it. Hope it can help some.

```
defmodule Sample1 do
  # combining Enum functions
  def find_indexes(collection, function) do
    Enum.filter_map(Enum.with_index(collection), fn({x, _y}) -> function.(x) end, elem(&1, 1))
  end
end

defmodule Sample2 do
  # implementing as similar way as Enum.find_index
  def find_indexes(collection, function) do
    do_find_indexes(collection, function, 0, [])
  end

  def do_find_indexes([], _function, _counter, acc) do
    Enum.reverse(acc)
  end

  def do_find_indexes([h|t], function, counter, acc) do
    if function.(h) do
      do_find_indexes(t, function, counter + 1, [counter|acc])
    else
      do_find_indexes(t, function, counter + 1, acc)
    end
  end
end

IO.puts "Sample1"
IO.inspect Sample1.find_indexes(["a", "b", "c", "b", "b"], fn(x) -> x == "a" end)
IO.inspect Sample1.find_indexes(["a", "b", "c", "b", "b"], fn(x) -> x == "c" end)
IO.inspect Sample1.find_indexes(["a", "b", "c", "b", "b"], fn(x) -> x == "b" end)

IO.puts "Sample2"
IO.inspect Sample2.find_indexes(["a", "b", "c", "b", "b"], fn(x) -> x == "a" end)
IO.inspect Sample2.find_indexes(["a", "b", "c", "b", "b"], fn(x) -> x == "c" end)
IO.inspect Sample2.find_indexes(["a", "b", "c", "b", "b"], fn(x) -> x == "b" end)
```

Executed as follows,

```
% elixir find.ex
Sample1
[0]
[2]
[1, 3, 4]
Sample2
[0]
[2]
[1, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @parroty! we can also do it with: `Enum.with_index(["a", "b", "c", "b", "b"]) |> Enum.filter_map(fn {x, _} -> x == "b" end, fn {_, i} -> i end)`

Comment: Yeah. This would be more elixir-like.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can zip the list with a range of `0..length(list)` and filter the list using the new item:

```
line = IO.read(:stdio, :all) 
|> String.split
|> Enum.zip(0..100)
|> Enum.filter(fn({_, x}) -> rem(x, 2) != 0 end)
|> Enum.map(fn({x, _}) -> "#{x}\n" end)
```

Which filter odd elements on the given list from stdin.

Please note that 100 in the range (`0..100`) must be the length of your list. I assumed I have a list of 100 items.